# Django 4 with drf_spectacular Swagger does not execute POST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I have the following classes using the `django-restframework` and `drf-spectacular`.
I can execute POST when I am logged in and through the drf default routes, but not using the `swagger-ui` routes.

I can go to this url: http:/example.com/api/schema/swagger-ui/#/organism/organism_create

[image]

But when I click the `Execute` button, nothing really happens. I expect the CURL command to be shown etc. Also, I don't see a response at the server backend. Contrary to the GET method. Here, the server prints: `11/Feb/2022 22:34:02] "GET /api/organism/ HTTP/1.1" 200 275`

I did go to login, and provided my username and password first.

What is wrong with this setup?

#### models.py

```
class Organism(models.Model):
    short_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    long_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    genus = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.long_label
```

#### serializers.py

```
class OrganismSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Organism
        fields = ('__all__')
```

#### views.py

```
class ReadOnly(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.method in SAFE_METHODS


class OrganismViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Organism.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.OrganismSerializer
    parser_classes = [parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.FormParser]
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'patch', 'delete']

    # Permissions
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated|ReadOnly]
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)
```

#### urls.py

```
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register('organism', views.OrganismViewset)
```

#### settings.py

I tried different settings. Using the `BasicAuth..`, I get a prompt asking for username and password, but still nothing happens.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        #'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
    #'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        #'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        #'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    #]
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        [
            'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
            'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
            'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        ]
     )    
}
```

When I try a to post something with Python's `request` module, the server prints:

```
Bad Request: /api/organism/
```

### However, this works using the DRF generated urls:

[image]

### Also GET requests work:

[image]

### POST with CURL also works:

```
curl -X 'POST' 'http://example.com/api/organism/'   -H 'accept: application/json'   -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'   -H 'X-CSRFTOKEN: ...'   -F 'short_label=adsfdsf'   -F 'long_label=asdfadf'   -F 'genus=adsfadfadf' --user "...."

{"id":4,"short_label":"adsfdsf","long_label":"asdfadf","genus":"adsfadfadf"}
```

Comment: Did you try Content Type as `application/json` instead of `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: You mean in the request body? The only other option is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. Though it seems like the Execute button is not working at all. Nothing is sent to the backend.

Comment: Do you get a `Bad Request` response when using `curl` or python's `request` module too? (I mean sending the Content Type as `application/json`).

Comment: Also set the `parser_classes` of your viewset to `JSONParser`. That's what defines the accepted Content Types.

Comment: The bad request comes with Python's request module. Here, I set the content type to 'application/json'.

Comment: Maybe it is a problem with the configuration of `drf-spectacular`.

Comment: After adding JSONParser, I now get _Unsupported Media Type: /api/organism/_.

Comment: if you use requests, you must tell it to use `multipart/form-data` for the post data. `drf-spectacular` does the right thing here and the settings are just fine. Use SwaggerUI to send a request. It should work.

Answer (score 3):

### you add this settings is useful for you

settings.py

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'COMPONENT_SPLIT_REQUEST': True,
}
```